# Looping all node of xml to get contributors

Tags: php, xml, loops, parsing

I have an XML [here](http://api.crossref.org/works/10.3855/jidc.4482/transform/application/vnd.crossref.unixsd+xml) which containing the list of authors

```
... 
<contributors>
    <person_name contributor_role="author" sequence="first">
        <given_name>John</given_name>
        <surname>Doe</surname>
    </person_name>
    <person_name contributor_role="author" sequence="first">
        <given_name>Micheal</given_name>
        <surname>Bob</surname>
    </person_name>
    <person_name contributor_role="author" sequence="additional">
        <given_name>Lyly</given_name>
        <surname>Jane</surname>
    </person_name>
    <person_name contributor_role="author" sequence="additional">
        <given_name>Tom</given_name>
        <surname>Mark</surname>
    </person_name>      
</contributors>
...
```

I tried this below code to get all authors with full name (given name and surname) but not working properly - shows blank values separated by ";" because I used so in my code.

```
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file($api_xml_url);
foreach($xml2 as $contributors =>$node) {
    foreach($node as $person_name => $child) {
        $authors = $child->given_name ." " .$child->surname ."; ";
        echo $authors;
    }
```

How to show all the authors in a sequence like John Doe; Micheal Bob; Lyly Jane; Tom Mark

Comment: What do you mean with "different sequence"? The order you give is exactly the order in the XML?

Comment: Each XML file has its different order. I mean how to get the full author with any value of sequence. Thanks

Comment: What does _"but not working (just only show ;)"_ mean? Your question is _super unclear_. Please show us both the expected results and the results you're currently getting. I also have no idea what you mean by "sequence" in this context.

Comment: Sorry my english is not good. My code only show the semicolon separated each author but not shown the given name and surname.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson He meant to get all the authors - no dependency on the sequence. Tried his code and it was showing blank values because of wrong code structure. I have corrected it and posted as an answer now.

Comment: @NguyenHoangBach Please check the answer posted below if this is what you are looking for. I hope you don't want to group the users by `sequence` name. If so, then let me know and I can update my answer to do so.

Comment: You can try with the full XML file http://api.crossref.org/works/10.3855/jidc.4482/transform/application/vnd.crossref.unixsd+xml

Comment: @NguyenHoangBach ahh ok.. here is the right XML you posted now. I am updating my answer in a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the basis of XML provided by you on this link: [XML File](http://api.crossref.org/works/10.3855/jidc.4482/transform/application/vnd.crossref.unixsd+xml)

Here is the solution:

```
foreach($xml2->query_result->body->query->doi_record->crossref->journal->journal_article->contributors as $contributors) {
   foreach($contributors as $person) {
       $author = $person->given_name ." " .$person->surname ."; ";
       echo $author;
   }
}
```

Tested and works fine.

Comment: Tried same code with XML provided in your question and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Can you have multiple contributors section in your XML?

Comment: Please try with this XML http://api.crossref.org/works/10.3855/jidc.4482/transform/application/vnd.crossref.unixsd+xml

Comment: Yes, multiple contributors

Comment: have also changed few variable names to make the code look good.